# Sql Query that returns columns with counts based on grouped values from one table

Tags: sql, group-by, count, case

I have a table of Tasks. There may be many tasks with various statuses to one Activity. I need to add columns to the main Activity view that displays the count of how many open tasks, closed tasks and total tasks.  I thought I would create a view with the totals grouped per Activity then join via the ActivityID.  I am having trouble creating the view with the correct figures, please help.This doesn't return the correct numbers:

The status values that equate to an 'OpenTasks' is 0,1 & 3.  'ClosedTasks' is 3

Existing table - Tasks

```
    ID          |  WorkID|    Status
    1           |  5     |    2
    2           |  5     |    2
    3           |  5     |    0
    4           |  5     |    3
    5           |  6     |    2
    6           |  7     |    0
    7           |  7     |    0
    8           |  9     |    1
    9           |  9     |    2
```

The resulting view I require is:

```
    WorkID | OpenTasks | ClosedTasks | TotalTasks
     5     | 2         | 2           | 4
     6     | 0         | 1           | 1
     7     | 2         | 0           | 2
     9     | 1         | 1           | 2
```

```
SELECT top 10000 WorkActivityId,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 2 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "ClosedTasks",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status <> 2 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "OpenTasks",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status < 10 then 1 ELSE NULL END) as "TotalTasks"
FROM    [SDMTWorkActivity].[WorkActivity].[Tasks]
GROUP BY WorkActivityId order by WorkActivityId
```

I am not great as SQL so appreciate any advice Thank you

Comment: The query you shared looks OK offhand. What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: I assume closed is `2` not `3`, based on the results and the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be working but you can try the following using `sum`

```
SELECT 
    WorkId,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status <> 2 then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "OpenTasks",
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 2 then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "ClosedTasks",
    SUM(CASE WHEN status < 10 then 1 ELSE 0 END) as "TotalTasks"
FROM [SDMTWorkActivity].[WorkActivity].[Tasks]
GROUP BY WorkId 
order by WorkId
```

output:

```
| WorkId | OpenTasks | ClosedTasks | TotalTasks |
| ------ | --------- | ----------- | ---------- |
| 5      | 2         | 2           | 4          |
| 6      | 0         | 1           | 1          |
| 7      | 2         | 0           | 2          |
| 9      | 1         | 1           | 2          |
```

Comment: Thank you very much - the numbers still didn't tally with another report - I have just found  out why - there was a deleted field in the table that I need to include in the where clause.  Thank you!